# Dynamically resize text in Div tag based on page resize and available space

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Here is an example what I will try to describe below: http://jsfiddle.net/9E3yJ/17/

When resizing the screen size to anything less than 930px, the right image wraps under the center div tag with text.  Is there a way to dynamicly have the center div tag resize itself and wrap the words so that the min-width becomes 67px and the right image does not wrap under the div tag until only the center div tag does not have any more room to wrap(min-width=67px) then ends up looking like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9E3yJ/18/

Thank You!

```
<style>
#logo {
display: block;
float: left;
line-height: 126px;
height: 130px;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo img {
margin: 5px 0 5px 17px;
}

#topText{
width: 210px;
height: 130px;
line-height: 130px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;


}

#topTextchild{
display:inline-block;
line-height:1;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#longPic {
width: 468px;
height: 60px;
display: block;
float: right;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 5px;
margin: 30px 17px 0 0;
background: rgb(190, 218, 247);
border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
</style
><div class="pageheader">


<div id="logo"><a href="http://www.sitelogo">
        <span></span>
        <img src="http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2008/01/04/confusedbird.gif" alt="Logo">
        </a>
</div>



<div id="topText">
    <div id="topTextchild">
    The needed Header Text For the top of the page.
    </div>
</div>


<div> 
    <div id="longPic"> 
    <a href="http://www.sitepicture">
    <span></span>
        <img src="http://nature-drops.puzl.com/puzl/images/3000/3281/gallery/51c870b940060.jpg" alt="image">
    </a>

    </div>
</div>

<span class="helper"></span>

</div>
```

BTW, the second thing I will be trying to do(after the center div tag can no longer shrink and eventually forces the right image under it) is use media tags to have different css for smaller screens and have the center text divs be full width and line up all the text in one row above the right image. This will make the center text be pushed above the right image instead of having the image go under the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options unless JavaScript could be used.

#### First

Use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    ...
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9E3yJ/20/

#### Second

Use `display: table` for *pageheader* and `display: table-cell` for its children - http://jsfiddle.net/9E3yJ/21/.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'll go with option 1 since it seems like the more modern way of doing it. Although there is a downside that the change is rapid and there is a wide gap between the text and the banner at one point.

The downside to second option is that I won't be able to get the right image to wrap under the text after it goes beyond the minimum width.